# How to obtained a percentage in java

Tags: java

## Problem

Write a program that reads the subtotal and the gratuity rate, then computes
the gratuity and total. For example, if the user enter 10 for subtotal and 
15% for gratuity rate, the program display $1.5 as gratuity and $11.5 as 
total.

## Code

```
package calculatetips;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateTips {



public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print(" Enter the subtotal : ");

   double subtotal  = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print(" Enter the gratuity rate : ");

   double gratuity = input.nextDouble();

   double caculateGratuity = (gratuity) / subtotal;

   double total = subtotal + caculateGratuity ;

   System.out.println(" The Gratuity is : $" +  caculateGratuity  + " and total is : $" + total);
  }  
}
```

## Issue

I am learning a java programing and I am stuck at a percentage. I am not sure how to obtained a percentage and my problem wants me to calculate  a gratuity of subtotal which is percentage of subtotal. I am feel so stupid about it please help me.

Comment: Stuck why? You will simply do something like `"%" + myCalcedNumb`  . Try try

Comment: Should be `double caculateGratuity = subtotal * gratuity / 100;`

Comment: Some light reading which will hopefully clear it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it now. I am feel so stupid now that I forget to do simply elemantry arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

So, if gratuity is a value between 0-100...

`calculateGratuity = (gratuity / 100) * subtotal` gives you the dollar amount of the tip.

Then, the rest of your code is correct.